# vba both checkbox trigger and dropdown triggers does work together

Tags: excel, vba

i have an excel file like the following:
[enter image description here][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLbE4.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVe6i.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLbE4.png)

this checkbox is being controlled by a trigger and the code is as follows:

```
   Sub CheckBox1_Click() 
If Range("CheckBox1").Value = True Then
        Range("ET").Rows.Hidden = True
    Else:
        Range("ET").Rows.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("CheckBox1").Value = True And Range("CheckBox1a").Value = True Then
        Range("A50:A53").Rows.Hidden = False
        Range("A61:A63").Rows.Hidden = False
    Else:
        Range("A50:A53").Rows.Hidden = True
        Range("A61:A63").Rows.Hidden = True
    
    End If
End sub
```

if the value of the checkbox is true, it hides rows "A50:A53" and"A61:A63" and unhides when the value is False. works perfect!
On the Same sheet, i have a dropdown that does the same stuff based on the selected option: following is the excel file:

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvCt0.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLbE4.png)

The same as the CheckBox, the dropdown option also, hides rows "A209:A210", if yes is selected. the triggers for the dropdown is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    ' Section 4. Testing part 1
    If Target.Column = 53 And Target.row = 208 Then
        If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
            Range("Addition").Rows.Hidden = False
            Range("A112:A113").Rows.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
            Range("A112:A113").Rows.Hidden = False
            Range("Addition").Rows.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End sub
```

The issue now is. When i start to work with the CheckBoxes, they work fine however the Dropdown doesn't respond and the same thing happens if the start to work with the dropdown, the checkboxes stop to respond.
Any suggestion or help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Side Note: `Target.Value = "Yes"` will give a mistmatch error if a user changes a range of cells at the same time. `Target.Value` returns a 2D array of values if more than one cell are the trigger for a Worksheet_Change event (If Target is a Range of cells). You can prevent this by specifying `.Cells(1)` to only refer to the first cell in the possible range of cells. Like `Target.Cells(1).Value = "Yes"`

Comment: Side Note: Ranges can be concatenated in VBA the same as how it is done in Excel. Instead of `Range("A50:A53")` & `Range("A61:A63")` being seperate lines, you can write `Range("A50:A53, A61:A63")`. Notice that the quotation marks are around the whole concatenated expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `CheckBox1_Click` try the `CheckBox1_Change` event. This will ensure the checkbox is updating every time the value changes, even if if doesn't gain or lose focus.

Other than that, you will need to have something in `Workbook_Open` that checks the default status of those checkboxes and ranges, hiding and showing rows as necessary.

You will also need a separate event just for `CheckBox1a`. Each `CheckBox_Change` script only triggers based on the named object in the script's title. For example `CheckBox1_Change` will only trigger for changes to a matching `CheckBox1` object. So if you want things to happen when the user clicks on `CheckBox1a` then you need a `CheckBox1a_Change` script.

Finally, you are retrieving and comparing checkbox values using `Range("CheckBox1")` which is not intended. There is a built in method for accessing these objects through VBA. Each CheckBox is added to the Worksheet object as a member. In the sheet's code module you can write `Me.CheckBox1.Value`. In an external code module you could write `Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value`.